# ASP.NET Core Task.WhenAll - A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-3.1

I started trying to convert my db queries to be async, but I really don't understand how to do it correctly.

I am now getting the error:

A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. This is usually caused by different threads using the same instance of DbContext. For more information on how to avoid threading issues with DbContext

```
public async Task<IList<MyObject>> GetAll(MyContext context)     {         
   return (await Task.WhenAll(     MethodA(context), MethodB(context)))     .SelectMany(e => e)     .ToList();
}

 private async Task<IList<MyObject>> MethodA(MyContext context)     {          
 return await context.MyThings.Include(x => x.Stuff)     
 //full query removed for readability 
.ToListAsync();     
}

 private async Task<IList<MyObject>> MethodB(MyContext context)     {          
 return await context.MyThings.Include(x => x.Stuff)     
 //full query removed for readability 
.ToListAsync();     
}
```

index.cs:

```
public Task<IList<MyObject>> MyDBList  { get; set; }

public void OnGet()     {              MyDBList = _myInterface.GetAll_context);

}
```

Index.cshml

```
      @foreach (var x in Model.MyDBList)     {
<p>x.ID</p>
}
```

I tired making the dbcontext transient, but it made no difference. I am also worried it will break a lot of my other code which updates entries in the db.

I can see why the error is happening, I am running two queries on the same context, but I don't know how to fix it.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: What the exception says, a DbContext isn't thread-safe. You use it in multiple threads, transient or not.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I understand why I am getting the error, but I don't know how to force it to use its own DBContext.

Answer (score 1):

> I can see why the error is happening, I am running two queries on the same context, but I don't know how to fix it.

The easiest way to fix it is to only run one query at a time:

```
public async Task<IList<MyObject>> GetAll(MyContext context)
{
  var resultsA = await MethodA(context);
  var resultsB = await MethodB(context);
  return resultsA.Concat(resultsB).ToList();
}
```

Even better, restructure `MethodA` and `MethodB` so that only one query is sent to the database.

Comment: This is what I had originally, but I was advise to try Task.WhenAll. That gives me the error 'cannot access a disposed object'. I actually have about 8 complex queries and I cant get them all into one.

Comment: Combining queries is often easier if your subqueries are `IQueryable`. If you don't want to combine queries, then do them one after another like my answer. If you want to run them concurrently (and still not combine them), then you'll need to create multiple db contexts, one for each query.

Comment: Your answer gives me the error 'cannot access a disposed object'? I cant work out how to create multiple dbcontexts? I was trying to use 'using (var context = new MyContext())', but I cant seem to pass the connection string from my appsettings.json. I am genuinely stuck, because every solution I find seems to have more problems.

Comment: It's possible that the disposal issue is due to an incorrect dependency injection setup. If you want multiple db contexts, the easiest way is probably to write your own db context factory.

Comment: My setup is just services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase"),
                    providerOptions => providerOptions.EnableRetryOnFailure())); in startup. Unfortunately my knowledge in ASP.NET isn't advanced and I don't have anyone I can learn from. I might have to backtrack and stop using async until I have more time to play with it..